# How to give prop only to first result of map in react?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I make a list of components from Array by using map.
I have to give prop only to the first result of the map.
How I can do it? (Give a prop only to an element Array[0]).

```js
if (dropDownOptions && Array.isArray(dropDownOptions)) {
      return (
        <ul className={styles.ul}>
          {dropDownOptions.map((option)=> (
          
            <DropDownItem
              iconName={option.iconName}
              value={option.value}
              displayValue={option.displayValue ? true : false}
              key={option.name}
              onClick={e => this.optionSelected()}
            >
              {option.props.children}
            </DropDownItem>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Why would do that? and what is in dropdownoptions?

Comment: Because the only first child will react on changed state of the parent component.

Comment: The callback function that you pass to the map function has a second parameter that is the current index of the array. You have to make sure the index is 0 and then pass the props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the first and all other elements using `filter` and then map over them.

```
if (dropDownOptions && Array.isArray(dropDownOptions)) {
  return (
    <ul className={styles.ul}>
      {/* first element */}
      {dropDownOptions.filter((e, i) => i === 0).map((option, i) => (
        <DropDownItem
          iconName={option.iconName}
          value={option.value}
          displayValue={option.displayValue ? true : false}
          key={option.name}
          onClick={(e) => this.optionSelected()}
        >
          {option.props.children}
        </DropDownItem>
      ))}
      {/* all other elements */}
      {dropDownOptions.filter((e, i) => i !== 0).map((option, i) => (
        <DropDownItem>
          {option.props.children}
        </DropDownItem>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if (dropDownOptions && Array.isArray(dropDownOptions)) {
      return (
        <ul className={styles.ul}>
          {dropDownOptions.map((option, i)=> (
          (i == 1) ? (
            <DropDownItem
              iconName={option.iconName}
              value={option.value}
              displayValue={option.displayValue ? true : false}
              key={option.name}
              onClick={e => this.optionSelected()}
             /> )
              :
           (your-child-here)
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dropDownOptions && Array.isArray(dropDownOptions)) {
  return (
    <ul className={styles.ul}>
      {dropDownOptions.map((option, index)=> (

        <DropDownItem
          iconName={index === 0 ? option.iconName : ''}
          value={option.value}
          displayValue={option.displayValue ? true : false}
          key={option.name}
          onClick={e => this.optionSelected()}
        >
          {option.props.children}
        </DropDownItem>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

};